# NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, web, formularios

Al ejecutar mi proyecto asp.net arroja el  siguiente  error

> [NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como
>   instancia de un objeto.]
>   Digita.Tustena.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   +94

si refresco la  pagina carga el  login siempre  hace  lo mismo. despues de poner usuario y contraseña . me  muestra el  siguiente error

> [NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como
>   instancia de un objeto.]    Digita.Tustena.Today.FillRep() +272
>   Digita.Tustena.Today.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +523
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +627

es  un  proyecto que me  dieron a  revisar es mas un crm. para  corregir ese  error
espero  puedan ayudarme

Comment: El error esta en el load de la pagina. Estas intentando acceder a un objeto que no ha sido instanciado como dice el error. Deberías poner el código de la pagina(code-behind) para que podamos ayudarte a identificar en donde esta exactamente el error.

Comment: Quetal Fran Islas. El  código es de un proyecto web obtenido de la siguiente pagina, https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=crm es un crm que  entiendo tenia  su  versión open source, estoy  intentando hacer funcionar  el proyecto, espero  puedan apoyarme

Comment: tras ir corrigiendo un error tras otro, logre ingresar. Aun así contiene muchas fallas...Es un código viejo, con una visual muy anticuada, no es responsive, algo fundamental hoy en dia y el %80 de los textos esta en ingles. Lo que yo veo es, un proyecto que te va a demandar muchísimo tiempo para corregir todos los errores y ponerlo al día. Mi recomendación: busca otro proyecto o inicia uno propio. Tal vez termines ahorrando tiempo incluso. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, Si ya  opte por  iniciar un proyecto nuevo. ese era  mi referencia,